# Permission on macOS messed up

Tags: macos, terminal, permission

I wanted to do `npm install -g`. As it didn't work due to permissions I took the approach suggested from the accepted answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47252451/permission-denied-when-installing-npm-modules-in-osx

> Change the owner of npm's directories to the name of the current user
> (your username):
>
> `sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(npm config get prefix)/{lib/node_modules,bin,share}`
>
> This changes the permissions of the sub-folders used by npm and some
> other tools (lib/node_modules, bin, and share).

then I could run my `npm install -g`. But this is not where the story ends. I wanted to install another package with npm. (`npm install identicon`).

I received the following error

```
npm does not support Node.js v12.0.0
You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.
You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/
....
```

And now I receive the same error over and over again, whenever I use a `npm` command.

On SO someone else had this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56805007/npm-warn-npm-does-not-support-node-js-v12-4-0?noredirect=1&lq=1 and the accepted answer suggested

> Fix /usr/local permissions:
>
> `sudo chown -R` id -un`:`id -gn `/usr/local`
>
> Clean npm cache and uninstall it:
>
> `npm cache clean -f` `npm -g uninstall npm`
>
> Reinstall node (with npm)
>
> `brew reinstall node`
>
> Upgrade npm:
>
> `npm -g i npm`

But the very first command failed:

```
chown: /usr/local: Operation not permitted
```

In case this helps:

```
/usr/local root# ls -la


total 0
-rw-r--r--    1 myuser  staff      0 Sep 20  2019 .com.apple.installer.keep
drwxrwxr-x    2 myuser  staff     64 Apr 24  2019 Caskroom
drwxrwxr-x  103 myuser  staff   3296 Nov 17 17:31 Cellar
drwxrwxr-x    3 myuser  staff     96 Nov 17 17:25 Frameworks
drwxrwxr-x   22 myuser  staff    704 Jan 14 05:49 Homebrew
drwxrwxr-x  409 myuser  staff  13088 Jan 14 05:49 bin
drwxrwxr-x   10 myuser  staff    320 Nov 17 17:23 etc
drwxrwxr-x  192 myuser  staff   6144 Nov 17 17:33 include
drwxrwxr-x  620 myuser  staff  19840 Nov 17 17:33 lib
drwxr-xr-x    5 myuser  staff    160 Mar 24  2019 man
drwxrwxr-x  124 myuser  staff   3968 Nov 17 17:34 opt
drwxr-xr-x    3 myuser  staff     96 Mar 24  2019 remotedesktop
drwxrwxr-x   12 myuser  staff    384 Nov 17 17:27 sbin
drwxrwxr-x   34 myuser  staff   1088 Nov 17 17:34 share
drwxr-xr-x    4 myuser  staff    128 Mar 24  2019 texlive
drwxrwxr-x    4 myuser  staff    128 May 16  2021 var
```

I want to use npm again and have my permissions fixed. Maybe someone can point out good ressources for beginners, which can guide me through the process, when I experience something similar. Thank you.

My macbookpro: macOS Catalina (10.15.7)

Comment: `sudo chown -R $(id -un):$(id -gn) /usr/local/*` should work. But please run `ls -l /usr/local/bin` first and add the result to the quesiton (instead of the listing of `/var/db/sudo` which doesn't matter here).

Comment: the result of `ls -l  /usr/local/bin` is couple hundred entries long, is this really right (feels wrong). Do you want to see a specific entry or a couple of entries?

Comment: If it is a couple of hundred, then by all means add them or (or put them on pastebin and share a link). there may be more things wrong then. But the intersting ones would be bin, share, lib and lib/node_modules.

Comment: used pastebin, to many characters for the body. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Ah, my bad. I wanted to see the content of /usr/local, not /usr/local/bin. Sorry for that, can you provide this (should be just a few lines)?

Comment: Permissions look ok

Comment: @nohillside How would you then explain my problem?

Comment: Did you upgrade node.js as the message said?

Comment: Which message do you mean? the one by @sbolel?

Comment: The one after "I received the following error" in your question.

Comment: no I did `npm install identicon` but I receive the same message also when I use e.g. `npm cache clean -f` it really does not matter what I write, I get this weird error, in the SO question linked the asker experienced the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `[nvm][1]` to install node for your user in `~/` to avoid using the system `node`, which requires permissions. `nvm` allows you to install and switch between multiple versions of `node`.

As stated in the readme:

> When using `nvm` you do not need `sudo` to globally install a module with npm -g, so instead of doing `sudo npm install -g npm`, do `npm i -g npm`

### 1. Prerequisites

Before you start, uninstall node if you have it installed with homebrew:

```
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies node 
brew uninstall --force node
```

### 2. install `nvm`

#### Option 1: Using `homebrew`

Install `nvm`:

```
brew update
brew install nvm
```

Create the nvm directory:

```
mkdir ~/.nvm
```

Add the following to ~/.zshrc:

```
export NVM_DIR="${HOME}/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm
```

#### Option 2 (preferred): manual installation

To install nvm manually, download and run the [install script](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/blob/v0.39.1/install.sh) and run it using either of the following cURL or Wget commands:

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash

wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash
```

If that doesn’t work, you can manually download the [install script](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/blob/v0.39.1/install.sh) and run it.

This creates a directory for nvm in `$HOME`:

```
mkdir ~/.nvm
```

And adds source lines from the snippet below to`~/.zshrc` which loads `nvm` in every new terminal shell:

```
export NVM_DIR="$([ -z "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME-}" ] && printf %s "${HOME}/.nvm" || printf %s "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/nvm")"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm
```

### 3. Load nvm

You can either `reset` your current shell, start a new one, or source the `.zshrc` changes:

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

To verify that nvm has been installed, do:

```
command -v nvm
```

which should output `nvm` if the installation was successful.

### 4. Install `node` using `nvm`

Install `node` 14 using `nvm` and set it as the default version:

```
nvm install 14
```

Make `node` 14 the default version:

```
nvm alias default 14
```

Set `default` as the current version to use:

```
nvm use default
```

Upgrade `npm` installed for `node` 14 to the latest version:

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```

Comment: how do I know if I installed it with homebrew? Can I look this up?

Comment: @YvesBoutellier you can run `brew list` and see if it comes up in the output

Comment: thanks! it was indeed installed with brew. I could install it manually. Why do you recommend node version 14?

Comment: I encountered a new error. Whenever I restart my computer, the nvm is not installed anymore. And node is the old version 12.0.0. The file .nvm is still there. When I manually run the installation script `. ~/.nvm/nvm.sh` and use `nvm install node` it works again. How can I make my changes persistent?

Comment: however brew list is not showing `node` anymore

Comment: did you add `export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm` and `source $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh` to your ~/.zshrc file?

Comment: what's the output of `command -v nvm`?

Comment: yes this worked: "`export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm` and source `$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh` to your ~/.zshrc file", now it's persistent